# Django Rest Framework nested serializer not showing related data

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I have a basic setup using the Django Rest Framework.  I have two models and a nested serializer setup:

```
# models.py

from django.db import models

class Plan(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length='100')

    def __unicode__(self):
        return u'%s' % (self.name)

class Group(models.Model):
    plan = models.ForeignKey('plan')
    name = models.CharField(max_length='50')
    weight = models.SmallIntegerField()

    def __unicode__(self):
        return u'%s - %s' % (self.name, self.plan.name)


# serializer.py

from plans.models import Plan, Group
from rest_framework import serializers

class GroupSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Group
        fields = ('name', 'weight')

class PlanSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    group = GroupSerializer(many=True, read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Plan
        fields = ('name', 'group')


# views.py

from rest_framework import viewsets

from plans.models import Plan
from plans.serializers import PlanSerializer

class PlanViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Plan.objects.all()
    serializer_class = PlanSerializer
```

When I view the serializers relationships in Django's Shell it shows the relationship correctly:

```
PlanSerializer():
name = CharField(max_length='100')
group = GroupSerializer(many=True, read_only=True):
    name = CharField(max_length='50')
    weight = IntegerField()
```

What I end up getting back via cURL is:

```
[
    {
        name: Test Plan
    }
]
```

What I expect to get back is:

```
[
    {
        name: Test Plan,
        group: [
                {
                    name: Test Group,
                    weight: 1
                }
        ] 
    }
]
```

There is no nested data coming through.  I'm at a lose for what I've not setup correctly here.  Can anyone point me in the correct direction?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The problem comes from your `queryset`: `queryset = Plan.objects.all()`. None of the items in this `queryset` has `.group` attribute that's why your result is empty. By default Django creates a reverse relation of the `plan` ForeignKey called `group_set` (unless you don't rename it via `related_name`) *(this means that every `plan` item in the `queryset` have a `group_set` attribute which is a queryset containing all the groups of this `plan`)*. You can use this attribute in order to get a proper serialization. This means to change:

```
class PlanSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    group_set = GroupSerializer(many=True, read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Plan
        fields = ('name', 'group_set')
```

If you really want to stick with `group` *(btw this is a very bad name for a list of groups)*. You can hack it with `prefetch_related` like so:

```
queryset = Plan.objects.prefetch_related('group_set', to_attr='group')
```

this way every `plan` item will have a `group` attribute - a `queryset` containing all the groups for this `plan`.

Comment: Appreciate the help.  I changed to `group_set` as I wasn't wed to the name and that fixed it.  I'll also look into changing the name from `group` to `categories` or something like that.

Comment: You can change the default xxx_set notation at the moment when you define the FK via `related_name`, e.g. `plan = models.ForeignKey('plan', related_name='groups')`. Now you wont have `group_set` attribute but `groups` instead.

Comment: This really helped me find the cause of my own issue.  I'd suggest adding your last comment Todor to your answer as having proper related_names in your model which the serializer can use seems a much more complete answer.

Comment: In my opinión @Todor's approach is the proper one, or at least looks cleaner than the accepted answer.

Comment: Thank you, Todor, just little ambiguous about the custom field naming in DRF. I thought I can name the field freely : )

Answer (score 2):

Never forget to give related name for the foreign key. for eg

In models

```
plan = modles.ForeignKey(Plan, related_name="plan")
```

In Serializers

```
plan = PlanSerializers(many = True, read_only = True)
```