# how to get all values of primary key related field nested serializer django rest framework

Tags: json, django, serialization, nested, django-rest-framework

I have the following models:

```
class SearchCity(models.Model):
    city = models.CharField(max_length=200)

class SearchNeighborhood(models.Model):
    city = models.ForeignKey(SearchCity, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    neighborhood = models.CharField(max_length=200)
```

and then the following nested serializer:

```
class CityNeighborhoodReadOnlySerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    searchneighborhood_set = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(many=True, read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = SearchCity
        fields = ('city','searchneighborhood_set')
        read_only_fields =('city', 'searchneighborhood_set')
```

paired with the view:

```
class CityNeighborhoodView(ListAPIView):
    queryset = SearchCity.objects.all()
    serializer_class = CityNeighborhoodReadOnlySerializer
```

when I make the api call I get this:

```
city: "Chicago"
    searchneighborhood_set: 
      0: 5 
      1: 4
      2: 3
city: "New York"
    searchneighborhood_set:
      0: 8
      1: 7
      2: 6
```

Im just getting the primary keys of the objects related. Which is good I need that, but I also want the `neighborhood` name how do I get that?

edit:

This question may shead some light. They are not using the primary key related serializer though, so my question would be (if this works of course, is what is the point of the primarykey related serializer then?

[Django Rest Framework nested serializer not showing related data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29651945/django-rest-framework-nested-serializer-not-showing-related-data)

Answer (score 7):

The answer was to not use the `primarykeyrelatedserializer` but rather the serializer used to serialize `Searchneighborhood` objects.

I changed this:

```
class CityNeighborhoodReadOnlySerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    searchneighborhood_set = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(many=True, read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = SearchCity
        fields = ('city','searchneighborhood_set')
        read_only_fields =('city', 'searchneighborhood_set')
```

to this:

```
class CityNeighborhoodReadOnlySerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    searchneighborhood_set = SearchNeighborhoodSerializer(many=True, read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = SearchCity
        fields = ('city','searchneighborhood_set')
        read_only_fields =('city', 'searchneighborhood_set')
```

and went from this output:

```
city: "Chicago"
    searchneighborhood_set: 
      0: 5 
      1: 4
      2: 3
city: "New York"
    searchneighborhood_set:
      0: 8
      1: 7
      2: 6
```

to the one I wanted:

```
city: Chicago
    searchneighborhood_set:
         0: {pk: 5, neighborhood: 'River North}
    ....
```

but now a new question arises, what is the point of a primary key realated serializer?