# What is an example use case of using primaryfieldserializer in django rest framework?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, serialization

I had a goal, to link cities and their neighborhoods together in a request response in a nested serializer. Neighborhoods have a Foriegn key to cities.

for clarity here are my models and serializer originally used.

```
class SearchCity(models.Model):
    city = models.CharField(max_length=200)

class SearchNeighborhood(models.Model):
    city = models.ForeignKey(SearchCity, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    neighborhood = models.CharField(max_length=200)

class CityNeighborhoodReadOnlySerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    searchneighborhood_set = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(many=True, read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = SearchCity
        fields = ('city','searchneighborhood_set')
        read_only_fields =('city', 'searchneighborhood_set')
```

but that returned only the neighborhood primary keys with the cities not a full city object.

This:

```
city: "Chicago"
    searchneighborhood_set: 
      0: 5 
      1: 4
      2: 3
city: "New York"
    searchneighborhood_set:
      0: 8
      1: 7
      2: 6
```

instead of what it should be, this:

```
city: Chicago
    searchneighborhood_set:
         0: {pk: 5, neighborhood: 'River North}
    ....
```

I got the above request, not by using primarykeyrelatedserializer but by using the serializer used for seralizing neighborhood objects which looks like this:

```
class SearchNeighborhoodSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = SearchNeighborhood
        fields = ('pk','neighborhood')
```

so now replace the primarykeyrealatedserializer with my neighborhood one and the proper nested serailzer is this:

```
class CityNeighborhoodReadOnlySerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    searchneighborhood_set = SearchNeighborhoodSerializer(many=True, read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = SearchCity
        fields = ('city','searchneighborhood_set')
        read_only_fields =('city', 'searchneighborhood_set')
```

so this begs the question, what is an actual use case for the primarykeyrelated serializer?

Also this is a question I created and then answered myself, after experimenting that has me raising this question.

[how to get all values of primary key related field nested serializer django rest framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49118885/how-to-get-all-values-of-primary-key-related-field-nested-serializer-django-rest)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some consumers only want/need the primary key of the object, really nothing more to it then that. Its just a different way to design the application.